# Excel IF AND OR multiple times

Tags: excel, if-statement

I've seen many questions on here relating to this topic but most seem to stop after 2 scenarios.
I'm trying to write a formula to say something like this:

IF this value is between these two values, output A. If the same value is between these other two values, output B. If the same value is between yet a further two values, output C and if the same value is between a last two further values, output D.

Here's what I have so far:
=IF(AND(Sheet1!C2>'Control Sheet'!B2,Sheet1!C2<'Control Sheet'!C2),"A",IF(OR(Sheet1!C2>'Control Sheet'!B3,Sheet1!C2<'Control Sheet'!C3),"B",IF(OR(Sheet1!C2>'Control Sheet'!B4,Sheet1!C2<'Control Sheet'!C4),"C",IF(OR(Sheet1!C2>'Control Sheet'!B5,Sheet1!C2<'Control Sheet'!C5),"D",""))))

But it only outputs "A" or "B" and stays on "B" if the value should be "C" or "D".. if that makes sense.

Is this possible in Excel? If so, what have I done wrong?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is totally possible in excel.  There's a slight mistake in your equation.

Look at this part of your equation:

`IF(OR(Sheet1!C2>'Control Sheet'!B3,Sheet1!C2<'Control Sheet'!C3),"B",...`

If the value is > the min value for B **OR** the value is < the max value for B then it outputs "B".  So if the value doesn't fall within the range for A, then it will always meet these conditions for B.

The fix is to change the ORs to ANDs.  The value must be > the min value **AND** < the max value.

`=IF(AND(Sheet1!C2>'Control Sheet'!B2,Sheet1!C2<'Control Sheet'!C2),"A",IF(AND(Sheet1!C2>'Control Sheet'!B3,Sheet1!C2<'Control Sheet'!C3),"B",IF(AND(Sheet1!C2>'Control Sheet'!B4,Sheet1!C2<'Control Sheet'!C4),"C",IF(AND(Sheet1!C2>'Control Sheet'!B5,Sheet1!C2<'Control Sheet'!C5),"D",""))))`

Comment: Thank you so much. I always get those the wrong way round!